GetFeatureInfo request on a layer styled with Heatmap render transform
I created a layer in Geoserver (version 2.20.2) styled with a heatmap rendering transformation as in this example: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation
A GetMap request on the layer works as intended.
Now, I want to get the value of the transform at the location of the user's click. As far as I understand, this should be possible with a GetFeatureInfo, which should return something like this:
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
   {
     "type": "Feature",
     "id": "",
     "geometry": null,
     "properties": {
       "GRAY_INDEX": 159,
       "custom name": "mid"
     }
   }
 ],
 "totalFeatures": "unknown",
 "numberReturned": 1,
 "timeStamp": "2021-03-19T11:50:32.433Z",
 "crs": null
}

Instead, I get this:
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": "fid--14841bba_19102baa9f1_-7fb0",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [...]
            },
            "geometry_name": "geom",
            "properties": {
                "grid": "DisposableGridCoverage[\"Process Results\", GeneralEnvelope[(6.555889124230343, 51.14765544940926), (6.990192407921749, 51.24382621739596)], DefaultGeographicCRS[\"WGS 84\"]]\r\n│   RenderedSampleDimension(\"Process Results\":[-3.4028234663852886E38 ... 3.4028234663852886E38])\r\n│     ‣ Category(\"Process Results\":[-3.4028234663852886E38 ... 3.4028234663852886E38])\r\n└ Image=WritableRenderedImageAdapter[]\r\n"
            }
        }
    ],
    "totalFeatures": "unknown",
    "numberReturned": 1,
    "timeStamp": "2024-07-30T10:52:06.073Z",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326"
        }
    }
}

I don't understand what is going on with that. These are the parameters of the request I am making to Geoserver:
SERVICE=wms&
VERSION=1.1.1&
REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&
LAYERS=optima:bosch_sensors_heatmap&
STYLES=optima:bosch_sensors_heatmap_style&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng&
SRS=EPSG:4326&
BBOX=6.555889124230343,51.14765544940926,6.990192407921749,51.24382621739596&
WIDTH=2530&
HEIGHT=894&
QUERY_LAYERS=optima:bosch_sensors_heatmap&
INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&
FEATURE_COUNT=100&
X=1100&
Y=356&


Strictly the request is missing the Format=...& and styles=...& parameters.  The output format is the INFO_FORMAT parameter. (OUTPUTFORMAT is not a WMS GetFeatureInfo parameter)

@nmtoken Thank you, I edited the question to include FORMAT and STYLES, and removed OUTPUTFORMAT. The response from Geoserver is the same though.
